# Javascript Couldn't Pickup InnerHTML

Tags: javascript

Here is my page element:

[image]

Then I tried to pick up the value `demo@....` from the element class name `user-name` using these code:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("user-name")[0].innerHTML; 
console.log("x is: " + x);
```

It would return me:

```
x is:
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Suggestion: can you create a minimal example with the code editor on StackOverflow? Your error wasn't `TypeError: undefined is not an object` so your document query found something, but wondering if it's still a timing issue.

Comment: I did suspect is timing issue, i tried place the javascript and the bottom of the page, still the same.

Comment: I tried using `window.onload()`, it still return null. any idea? I also tried using `document.getElementById().innerHTML` after assigned an ID on that element.

Comment: What sets the value on `.user-name`, is the value set on the server or dynamic in the browser?

Comment: set on the server. anyhow, i had used a different approach to resolve this. basically is to obtain the information from server and write again instead of reading from the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your approach, the code `innerHTML` should have worked, there might be some other issue which might be occurring.
Like 1) there might be other tag with same class name, 2) the username value might not be updated when you called the function.

Comment: I will try using `window.onload` see if works.